# Text extract and adding to new column

Tags: r, regex

Hi I am trying to kill two bird with one stone.

Firstly if col b is populated get it to new (no issue here) and secondly if col b is blank extract part of the string - everything after Task and before space and input to "new".

```
a <- c("11-010 Bla", "TASK 21 MMM", "TASK 03-11-11 Hah")
b <- c("11-010","","")
new <- c("","","")

df <- data.frame(a,b,new)


a                 b          new
11-010 Bla        11-010    
TASK 21 MMM
TASK 03-11-11 Hah
```

Output:

```
a                 b          new
11-010 Bla        11-010     11-010   
TASK 21 MMM                  21       
TASK 03-11-11 Hah            03-11-11
```

I tried to get the task number using below but I am unable to add space to it. The task number is always followed by space.

```
gsub("^[^_]*TASK|\\.[^.]*\\s$", "", df$a)
sub(".*?TASK=(.*?)' '.*", "\\1", df$a)
```

Comment: Is this what you need `sub("^.*(\\d+).*$", "\\1", df$a)`?

Comment: You only have one number there? If so then `gsub('\\D+', '', df$a)` will also work

Comment: `ifelse(df$b!="", df$b, sub(".*TASK ([^ ]+) .+", "\\1", df$a))` (with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to construct `df` to avoid the conversion to `factors`)

Comment: Please see edited. Task number will run into number similar to 01-01-101-1 and the start is text TASK and end space.

Comment: @Kalenji my code line works whatever is between "TASK" and the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture, in case `b` is an empty string everything that is between "TASK " and the space with the following `regex`:

```
sub(".*TASK ([^ ]+) .+", "\\1", df$a[df$b==""])
# [1] "21"       "03-11-11"
```

`\\1` permits to capture what is in between brackets in the regex, which, in this case, is `[^ ]+`: anything but a space, one or more times.

You can put that directly in `df` with:

```
df$new[df$b==""] <- sub(".*TASK ([^ ]+) .+", "\\1", df$a[df$b==""])
#                  a      b      new
#1        11-010 Bla 11-010   11-010
#2       TASK 21 MMM              21
#3 TASK 03-11-11 Hah        03-11-11
```

Comment: What about if the text does not have work "Task", above code return full text. Any way around it? a <- c("11-010 Bla", "TASK 21 MMM", "TASK 03-11-11 Hah", "Some text without TASK")  b <- c("11-010","","", "")  df <- data.frame(a,b) df$new[df$b==""] <- sub(".*TASK ([^ ]+) .+", "\\1", df$a[df$b==""])

Comment: you'll need either keywords (like "TASK" is) or a pattern for the data to keep in order to "recognize" what to capture in  your string

Comment: @Cath you can actually capture the words using the spaces, without having to use the names:`sub("?(.*\\s)?(\\d.*?\\s).*","\\2",a)` which will give you.`[1] "11-010 "   "21 "       "03-11-11 "`

Answer (score 0):

```
sub("?(.*\\s)?(\\d.*?\\s).*","\\2",a)
[1] "11-010 " "21 " "03-11-11

regmatches(a,regexpr("\\d.*?\\s",a))
[1] "11-010 "   "21 "       "03-11-11 "
```